# Excel formula to seek if the last value falls within a certain period

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of data full of blanks and would like a formula that is able to tell me how many and the total value of those values.

For example there are several rows that have values in 202402 although the highlighted row has its last non 0 value in 202402.

I have attempted to use XLOOKUP, `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,G20:R20<>"",ROW(G20:R20)-ROW(N20)+1,0,0,-1)`. But have not been successful.

I am not looking for the last non 0 value in general. Just to see if the non 0 value falls within 202402.

That is what I am looking to find, how many of these exist.

[image]

Comment: No, I am trying to find the last non 0 value in a particular period.

Comment: I have tried your formula and it is giving me the last non 0 value in general. Not for a specific period.

Comment: each row is categorised for this specific project and the figures relate to the time period of sales under these categories. My expected output is to seek which categories have a non 0 value as their last figure for 202402.

Comment: Editing post and by removing the words `Count` & `Sum` definitely do not help. You need to show how your formula would return the count and sum. please show the expected output.

Comment: Again in your comments: **each row is categorised for this specific project and the figures relate to the time period of sales under these categories. My expected output is to seek which categories have a non 0 value as their last figure for 202402.** which category there is no category shown in the post or in the screenshot

Comment: For the sake of this particular task we can utilise 1-62 to label the categories if that assists in achieving this goal.

Comment: Also by the formula you were trying does it have to be like this,.`=XLOOKUP(1,--(A2:L2>0),COLUMN(A2:L2),"",,-1)` dont think it should be `ROW()` function you need the `COLUMN()` function here.

Comment: Doesn’t have to be like that. I can try the row method. What would the formula look like then?

Comment: Try and let me know: `=XLOOKUP(1,--(A2:A18>0),ROW(A2:A18),0,,-1)`

Comment: This formula is not what I am after. I am not looking for the last non 0 value in general. Just to see if the non 0 value falls within 202402.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: So what should be the output? When you say as per your edit, then applying a formula what will the output return.

Comment: can you please message me privately? I believe there is a misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, and understood correctly the last non zero value for a period can be achieved by the following formula as well:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(TAKE(TOCOL(A2:A18/(A2:A18<>0),2),-1),0)
```

---

Or use `BYCOL()` to spill for the whole row:

```
=BYCOL(A2:L18,LAMBDA(α, IFERROR(TAKE(TOCOL(α/(α<>0),2),-1),0)))
```

---

Also one could use a `LOOKUP()` function:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A18>0),A2:A18),"None")
```

---